# Tax documents in Italy

Tags: taxes, european-union, italy

One of my cousins had a major injury on the road in Italy - January 2013. Previous to that he has decided to move there, and had all the required documents, residency, health insurance, IDK. For now is in hospital here, but he plans to return there, as soon  the situation becomes manageable.

He has no property and no other income in Italy other than the one for the invalidity. 700 Euro's in each month (I think). For now he has to apply for the 730 document. Do you have any idea, about how to properly fill those documents?

Comment: When you say 'here', do you mean the US?

Answer (score 1):

Modello 730 is a tax declaration. As Italian tax law is pretty complex, the best way would be to look for a 'commercialista' (Italian tax advisor) which will fill the 730 for you.

Or you can dare to fill it by yourself, but as I said it edges madness.

Comment: Also, if you want I may share several contacts.

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm late, as the 730 was due July, but this might help someone else in the future.

I would strongly advise you against trying to do his 730 yourself, unless you have a **very** strong command of Italian.

The 730 compilation manual is written using obscure legal speech and is quite hard to understand. 
In legal speech common words can have a completely different meaning from what they normally do, and unless you're really good at feeling that "this is not quite right here" you may never notice.

I'm Italian and even I had a lot of trouble understanding some key passages of the manual, especially the section about life insurance.

One thing you could try, if your cousin has a PIN Dispositivo INPS (access code to log in to INPS' online services), is to log in to there and see if he has a **730 precompilato** and it's acceptable to him (e.g. it doesn't say he should pay an additional €750,000,000 in taxes for some reason).

This is a pre-compiled 730 module that the Italian IRS gives you, and if you accept it as is you're exempt from any fiscal checks and any repercussions even if it's wrong.

Comment: Note that the question was posted in 2014.

Comment: Derp. I noticed it was posted in May, but not of which year... I'm not even sure the 730 precompilato was even a thing yet in 2014.

Comment: No real worries; we tend to prefer questions and answers that are relatively timeless. So there's no harm in answering old questions, especially if you can contribute something that hasn't yet been said (which, without knowing the specifics, it does look like this answer does). Welcome to the site!